# Python - characters that identify the start and end of a string

Tags: python, string, split

I am trying to print a portion of a string between a start character and a stop character, such as `12345!678!91011` (the start and stop character being '!'), where I only want to print out `678`.

However so far I've only been able to either print out the first section or the whole string without any `!`. I'm having problems figuring out how I can print out just the section between the `!` while both start and stop characters are the same.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Please [edit] to include a [mcve] including code for what you've tried so far, so that we can better understand how to help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can just split the string into a python list and take its middle element like this:

```
x = "12345!678!91011"

wrap = x.split("!")[1]

print(wrap)
```

this should print out `678`.
Note that the result will obviously be a string, if you wanted it an `int` you should have done it something like this: `wrap = int(x.split("!")[1])`.

Comment: This worked, thank you very much

Comment: @Crouton if this answered to your question remember to click on the "accept" sign under the answer scoring, so that other people looking around for the same reason know that this solved the problem :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
String = ""
#This finds the index of the first "!" 
x = String.index("!")
#This starts x at the chat right after the "!" 
x = String[x+1:]
#This is the Second string
Substring="" 
#This goes through x to find the second "!"
for char in x:
    #if Found it stops the loop
    If char =="!" :
        break
    #If not it adds char to the substring
    else:
        Substring+=char
print(Substring)
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried regex?

```
import re

X = "12345!678!91011"
substr = re.search(r"!(.+)!", x).groups()[0]

print(substr)
```

EDIT:
The regex, for those unfamiliar with regex syntax, simply says, find the patter `!` followed by any character, once or more times, and terminating with `!`. The parenthesis put anything in between the two `!` in a group, which can then be accessed once matched. Here we are just finding the first match.